# How to use DateField in an ArrayField in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, datepicker, django-postgresql

I'm trying to use `ArrayField` in my model. I get it working with, e.g., `IntegerField`, but not `DateField`. So I'm wondering, is there some limitation I'm not aware of, or is there a bit missing in my code that prevents it from working?

In my models.py, I added the field with

```
class Directive(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ...
    individual_dates = ArrayField(
        models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, blank=True, default=date.today),
        default=list,)
    test = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(blank=True), default=list,)
    ...
```

and in my forms.py, I have

```
class DirectiveForm(forms.ModelForm):

    individual_dates = SimpleArrayField(
        forms.DateField(), required=False,
        help_text='comma separated list of dates',
        widget=DatePickerInput(options={'format': 'DD.MM.YYYY'}))
    test = SimpleArrayField(
        forms.IntegerField(), required=False,
        help_text='comma separated list of ints')

    ...
```

The form renders fine:
[image: fields as rendered with template]

Now,

- when I enter a comma seperated list of integers in the "test" field, the values are stored in the database as expected.
- when I try to enter a number of dates in the "individual dates" field using the DatePicker, every pick overwrites the previous one, and the last one is eventually stored in the database.
- when I enter a comma separated list of dates by hand, only the first entry is stored in database.

But,

- when I use the django shell, import my model and try to enter dates there, it works as expected:

```
>>> Directive.objects.create(individual_dates=[date(2024,2,2), date(2024,3,1), date(2024,4,6)])
>>> Directive.save()
>>> Directive.objects.last().individual_dates
[datetime.date(2024, 2, 2), datetime.date(2024, 3, 1), datetime.date(2024, 4, 6)]
```

So, what am I doing wrong in my forms.py (or in my template?) which prevents the ArrayField to store all values? Do I need to customize the `clean()` method to correctly account for dates? But that wouldn't solve the issue with the DatePicker...

Comment: Please *don't* use `ArrayField`s, it makes the database violating *first normal form*.

Comment: Okay, then what's the alternative for my use case: A kind of to-do list, which should display tasks on a set of individual dates?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @willem-van-onsem. As you might have guessed, I'm not very familiar with database design. But it got me researching, and I guess I'll go with a dedicated model for my individual dates and linking them to my tasks with ForeignKeys. It makes me wonder, however, why PostgreSQL has a dedicated ArrayField, if it is against such a basic rule?